# Restore a minimised application via VBS within an HTA

Tags: vbscript, restore, hta, minimize

I have an HTA that is minimised while it carries out a backup.  After this backup is complete I'd like to restore the HTA, but I'm having trouble.

I've tried a few things (below), but with no success.  Is anyone able to point me towards a definitive solution?

First I tried to simply activate the HTA, but this failed.  I'm no expert, but my understanding is that doing this should mimick a mouse click on the HTA in the task bar, thus restoring it -

```
Sub RestoreBackupHTA()

    Shell.AppActivate "Backup"

End Sub
```

Next I tried to activate the HTA and then send the keys to "restore" the active window, but that also failed -

```
Sub RestoreBackupHTA()

    Shell.AppActivate "Backup"
    Shell.SendKeys "% r"

End Sub
```

Finally I tried to first activate the HTA and then send the keys to "restore" the active window after a short timeout (I found a couple of posts suggesting this could help to ensure that the HTA was fully active before sending the keys to restore it), but again, failure -

```
Sub RestoreBackupHTA()

    Shell.AppActivate "Backup"
    Call window.setTimeout("RestoreBackupHTAAfterWait", 500, "VBScript")

End Sub

Sub RestoreBackupHTAAfterWait()

    '** Create a tempory Shell object (required as the global Shell object is out of scope for some reason *'
    Dim tmpShell
    Set tmpShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    tmpShell.SendKeys "% r" ' Restore the HTA

    Set tmpShell = Nothing  ' Destroy the tmpShell object

End Sub
```

**Notes** -

1. The HTA has the ID "Backup" (`<HTA:APPLICATION ID="Backup" ... />, and so "Backup" is displayed in the title bar when it is running (and as the title in the task manager).  This is why I'm using it as the`title`parameter for`Shell.AppActivate`, and according to [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) that should be correct.
2. `Shell` is declared and set globally, thus it is available to the `RestoreBackupHTA` procedure in the examples above.

Comment: How has your HTA been minimized for a backup carrying out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. It seemed to work for me. My window title shows the full path to the hta, so I just tried the following (after using `setTimeout`):

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .AppActivate("test.hta")
    .SendKeys "% r"
End With
```

And didn't have any problems.

But here's another one way. You can use [`nircmd`](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) (always handy to have on hand).

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "nircmd.exe win normal ititle Backup"
```

This will restore any windows with "Backup" in the title. You can filter many ways (title, class, PID, etc) if you need finer control.

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion of `nircmd` generates an error, and your other suggestion yeilds the same results as my own work.  I have been doing some more testing though, and it appears (bizarrely) that if I click on another applicatoin during the backup (when the HTA is minimised) it will then be restored.  If I don't click off of it and instead sit and wait, it is not restored.

Comment: If you go the `nircmd` route, you'll need to make sure you put the executable in a folder that's included in your `path` environmental variable, like `c:\windows`. Otherwise, you'll need to specify the full path to the exe in your `Run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using HTA, you can make use of the `SINGLEINSTANCE` parameter

```
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="RestoreMe" SINGLEINSTANCE="yes">
```

so that when you relaunch the HTA application it will trick windows to restore the existing HTA application:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run location.href
```

To illustrate this, I created a mock HTA application which you must minimize within the first 5 seconds of launching it. After 5 seconds, it will restore itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Restore Me</TITLE>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="RestoreMe" SINGLEINSTANCE="yes">
<SCRIPT language="VBScript">
Sub RestoreMe
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.run location.href
End Sub
Call window.setTimeout("RestoreMe", 5000)
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but rather bizzarely this seems to spawn additional instances of the HTA as opposed to restoring the original. In turn, each newly spawned instance then spawns another new instnace.  I left may desk for 5 minutes and had about 65 instances running upon return!