# How do i keep the window size on my batch file after opening it in minimized mode?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a VBscript that runs a bunch of programs, one of them being a batch file. In the batch file i use:

```
Mode 50,8
```

This makes the window the right size and makes it look nice. However, in the cases where i open the batch file using the VBscript i want it to be minimized, that is done like this:

```
objShell.Run("path_of_my_batch_file"),7
```

The problem is that this makes the batch file completely ignore the instructions to stay at "Mode 50,8" and open the batch file in the default CMD size.

So my question is: How can i open my batch file in minimized mode using my VBS-file, but also let it keep the size?

Putting this at the top of the batch file workes:

```
Pause
Mode 50,8
```

But that means i have to press a key before it gets the right size and i defenetly dont want that. I need a way to either run the "Mode 50,8" command as soon as the batch file is no longer minimized or a way to let it keep the size after the VBS-file minimizes it.

Comment: Have you tried a `timeout /t 1>NUL` instead of the pause?

Comment: The problem is the the mode has to be set when the window is no longer minimized, so a timeout solution doesn’t work if i want to wait a undefined amount of time before using the batch file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `mode 50,8` command desn't seem to have an effect while in minimized state.

- There are
  [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801000/restore-a-minimised-application-via-vbs-within-an-hta)
  with .appac  tivate and then using sendkeys but
- I'd prefer the [3rd party app NirCMD](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) which enables the batch to minize/restore
  itself.

---

```
' Q:\Test\2018\07\23\SO_51469493.vbs
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("Q:\Test\2018\07\23\SO_51469493.cmd")
```

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\23\SO_51469493.cmd
@Echo off
Title Min5x80
Mode 80,5
Echo now minimizing using:
Echo nircmd win min title Min5x80
Timeout /t 5 & nircmd  win min    title Min5x80
Timeout /t 5 & nircmd  win normal title Min5x80
cls
Echo back again
Pause
```

This will involve a flicker when running the batch.

Comment: I had hoped to avoid 3rd party programs, but i guess this will have to do until i find any better solutions.